# Javascript onClick() event not working when used dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I'm struggling to make the onclick event listener work in my results.
here is my code:

```
function createLink(text, parentElement) {
        var a = document.createElement('p');
        var linkText = document.createTextNode(text);
        a.appendChild(linkText);
        temp1 = text.replace("/","-");
        temp2 = res1.replace("/","-");
        a.onclick=function(){goMainMenuFromResults();};
        parentElement.appendChild(a);
        var br = document.createElement('br');
        parentElement.appendChild(br);
}
```

The line in question is:

```
a.onclick=function(){goMainMenuFromResults();};
```

The function is present in another  section but works in the hardcoded html events. I just can't make it work when its imported into the element in javascript.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Should be `a.onclick(function(){goMainMenuFromResults();});`

Comment: @aldrin27: No, that would fail with a TypeError.

Comment: Yes it failed with an error

Comment: James, are there any console errors? I assume the new element is appearing. Are you sure this code can reach the `goMainMenuFromResults()` function?

Comment: Sorry about that. it's pure javascript.

Comment: What is res1? Can you advise?

Answer (score 1):

James, it seems to work fine, just a var called res1 was getting error here. Take a look:

```
temp2 = res1.replace("/","-");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MarcelKohls/23tBM/291/

Comment: Hi thanks so much for pointing this out! it still doesnt link. Is it something to do with my parent? it's got a scroll overflow and positon: absolute I cant think what it could be!

Comment: James, did you see the code working on jsfiddle? I believe that the scroll and the position are not the problem. Maybe there is another problem on the code. Send us a sample of the code showing how you are using it, or a sample page, so we can see it.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the lines containing variables that were not defined. I then added a call to preventDefault() on the event raised inside the event handler. And it now works fine. New elements are created and the click handler works on the new elements.

```
function createLink(text, parentElement) {
    var a = document.createElement('p');
    var linkText = document.createTextNode(text);
    a.appendChild(linkText);
    //temp1 = text.replace("/","-");
    //temp2 = res1.replace("/","-");
    a.onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        goMainMenuFromResults();
    };
    parentElement.appendChild(a);
    var br = document.createElement('br');
    parentElement.appendChild(br);
}
```